# How i can send an unsubscribes link into a mail for the user on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, email, unsubscribe

I have an option in the admin section of the site that is built with WordPress from there i can send email for each subscriber with some contents and images or anything that i want. now i want to send an unsubscribe link with email that will sent to the user.Any help on this will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just want them to unsubscribe so that you can't mail them or you want to delete there account as well. Also, are you using any plugin for the same?